# Seeing what looks like a "declared" keyword in python

Tags: python, char, keyword

I'm taking an online Python course, and while I'm in over my head at the sign-in prompt, I'm still having at it.

An example is given in the online text (for a palindrome program) where it gives as an example:

```
def toChars(s):
    s = s.lower()
    ans = ‘ ‘
    for c in s:
        if c in ‘abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’:
            ans = ans + c
    return ans
```

what is giving me fits is how the 'c' gets understood by Python. From what I can gather, the 'c' is treated as a keyword, understood as a keyword for 'char,' but where does Python get that?  There's no explanation that I've found anywhere, wondering if anyone can set me straight on this.

Comment: To check if something is a keyword just do `import keyword; print(keyword.kwlist)` (in the interactive interpreter) and see if you find it there.

Answer (score 4):

`c` is not a keyword, it's a variable name.

In Python, strings are iterable. When you iterate over a string, it yields its characters one by one.

Thus the following:

```
for c in s:
```

simply iterates over the characters of `s` and assigns each character in turn to `c`.

Comment: So simply declaring it makes it work?  Seems like I get biatch slapped by idle every time I try doing that.

Comment: I expected python to go "Yeah, there's a c in there. There's also an a, a b, a w...too"

Comment: @LarryPotterbaum within the for loop c is now a temporary variable just called c, you could rename it TEMPVAR or something else. On each pass of the for loop we iterate over the string character by character, each time c points to the new position (or character) in the string.

Comment: @Igriffiths: The c is not "temporary". It is a local variable as any other old local variable.

Answer (score 1):

All `for c in s:` does is takes one character in `s`, assigns it to the variable `c`, then executes the `for` loop body. Then, it assigns the next character in `s` to `c` and s on.

For example, let `s = "LARRY123"`. First, `s = s.lower()` will assign `"larry123"` to `s`. Within the `for` loop, `c` is first set to `'l'`. Then `if c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":` checks whether `c` is a letter and if it is, then it appends it to `ans`. In the next iteration, `c` is equal to `'a'`. Then `'r'`. And so on. When `c` is `1`, `2` or `3`, it will not be appended to `ans` because it is not an alphabet.

In the end, `ans` will be `larry`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was just checking http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types and section 5.6.2 - Conversion shows that c is indeed what Python uses as a way to iterate over characters. Thanks everybody.